# Transitions for Dropdown Menus in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, webkit, transition

I have created a website with a horizontal drop down menu that works perfectly fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer. The menu is just HTML and CSS, no jQuery or JavaScript.

I've tried with and without transitions but cannot seem to get the menu to work properly. There are random occurrences when the menu does drop-down on the hover, but not always.

Can anyone give any suggestions on how to make this code work for Internet Explorer? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code with transitions (and can also be seen live at lifestylespacedesign.com):

CSS:

```
#menu ul li {
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid #8EC2CF;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
    color: #000;    
}

#menu ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

#menu ul li ul li { 
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: block; 
    color: #777;
    border-right: none;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

EDIT: Here is a JSFiddle with the HTML and CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/mfraser801/DJKL5/

Comment: Providing your targeted version of IE would be extremely helpful and make it easier for you to receive an answer. Unfortunately, IE does not auto-update like several of the other modern browsers so version is a major issue.

Comment: can you prodive a fiddle and which IE version that you are using

Comment: **"random occurrences"**...does not sound like a CSS issue to me.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle with the HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/mfraser801/DJKL5/. Any help would be greatly appreciated!